# Добавление изображения в SQl таблицу

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

Создаю Форум с добавлением текста и изображения.Вот уже который день не могу загрузить изображение в таблицу данных.Прощу помочь.В этой сфере новичок)А есть ли более улучшенный вид для хостинга изображения?

```
@Controller
public class PostController {


    @Autowired
    CategoryService service;
    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;
    @Autowired
    SubCategoryService subcategory;
    @Autowired
    PostService postService;


    private Date getDate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        return calendar.getTime();
    }


    @GetMapping("/post")
    public ModelAndView gotoPost(Principal principal) {
        String user = principal.getName();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("post");
        List<CategoryEntity> cate = service.getAllCategorys();
        List<Subcategory> cate2 = subcategory.getAllSubcategory();
        model.addObject("user", usersService.getUsersByUsername(user));
        model.addObject("category", cate);
        model.addObject("subcat", cate2);
        return model;
    }

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public ModelAndView postNewPost
            (HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("myImage") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        PostEntity entity = new PostEntity();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("post");
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
        int categoryId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtCategory"));
        int subCategoryId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtSubCategory"));

        entity.setUserId(userId);
        entity.setCategoryId(categoryId);
        entity.setSubcategoryId(subCategoryId);

        if (file != null) {

                System.out.println("Saving file:   " + file.getOriginalFilename());

                entity.setLogo(file.getOriginalFilename());
                entity.setFileData(file.getBytes());


                entity.setText(request.getParameter("Text"));
                entity.setDate(getDate());
                postService.savePost(entity);

                model.addObject("message", "succes");
                model.setViewName("post");


        } else {
            model.setViewName("401");

        }

        return model;
    }

}
```

это html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 th:text="${message}"></h1>
    <h2>Form control: textarea</h2>
    <p>The form below contains a textarea for comments:</p>
    <form th:action="@{/post}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="userId" th:value="${user.id}"></input>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="FormControlSelect1">Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="FormControlSelect1" name="txtCategory">
                <option th:each="cate:${category}" th:text="${cate.categoryName}" th:value="${cate.id}" ></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="FormControlSelect2">Subcategory</label>

            <select class="form-control" id="FormControlSelect2" name="txtSubCategory">
                <option th:each="subcategory:${subcat}" th:text="${subcategory.subCateName}" th:value="${subcategory.id}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="myImage">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose image file...</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="Text" rows="5"  id="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-danger right" value="Gonder">
    </form>
</div>
```

Выводится ошибка

> Incorrect string value: '\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE1&\xD9...' for column
>   'file_data' at row 1

Comment: А у вас в БД поле file_data какого типа?

Comment: А зачем вам забивать базу тонной картинок? Положите картинку в ФС с неповторимым именем и сохраните его название в базе.

Comment: Chubatiy--ты был прав.Проблема заключалась в типе Базы данных.Поменял тип БД на "bloob",Вроде картинки сохраняются.Но мне нужно реализовать Добавления нескольких картинок.И вывод картинок из базы.

Comment: Maxim --А каким способом это реализовать.Если честно мне тоже  не понравился метод сохранения файлов в БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создайте файл в диске D:// а в mysql нужно хранить просто path фотографии вот пример это из моего проекта поменяйте параметры по вашему
во первых в application.properties объявим место папки который мы создали в диске D:/ чтобы объявить напишем этот строка в  application.properties

```
springBlog.user.pic.url=D:\\имя папки\\
```

потом в контроллере объявим переменный по типу String и дадим value на эту строку это выглядит вот так

```
@Value("${springBlog.user.pic.url}")
private String examplePicture;
```

потом у нас есть метод для добавлении фотографии вот

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/addPicture")
public String addArticle(@ModelAttribute("Имя вашего модела") Model model, @RequestParam("pict") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(examplePicture);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    String picName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    multipartFile.transferTo(new File(dir, picName));
    model.setImage(picName);
    ModelRepository.save(model);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

потом в html создадим форма

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/addPicture}" th:object="${***}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="pict">-здесь дадим параметр который мы дали в методе
    <input type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за подробное объяснение.Сделал так как сказали,Все хорошо но есть одно но

Comment: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.

Comment: multipart.max-file-size=30MB
multipart.max-request-size=80MB         Даже добавил эти настройки в пропертис но увы ошибка не исправилась

Comment: у вас файл слишком большая выберите маленький файл и все будет ок

Comment: у вас получилось?

Comment: да.проблема решилась.Благодарю за отзыв

Comment: пожалуйста отметите ответ как решение то есть ставьте птичку на ответ

Comment: Okay vse.если знаете плиз ответьте на мой второй вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1 (Не самый лучший)
Конвертировать файл в строку Base64 и сохранить в базу.

```
//Конвертируем байты з файла в строку Base64
byte [] byteArr=file.getBytes();
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArr);
//Конвертируем строку назад в байты
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
```

Вариант 2
1. Добавляем глобальную переменную.

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

2. Получаем реальный путь на сервере, создаем файл и копируем наш MultipartFile в созданий файл

   ```
   String uploadsDir = "/uploads/";
   String realPathtoUploads =  
           request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(uploadsDir);
   if(! new File(realPathtoUploads).exists()) {
        new File(realPathtoUploads).mkdir();
   }

   String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
   String filePath = realPathtoUploads + orgName;
   File dest = new File(filePath);
   file.transferTo(dest);
   ```